# Animation images not rendering properly

Tags: css

I tried different image rendering with animation, but its not rendering properly if it is 2 images, the same css if 5 images then it will render properly.

i got this code online only, i just changed for my requirement, i need to show only 2 images , can anyone support this issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-with-multiple-images

**scenario 1:**
image tag: 5

css: animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;

*working fine above code*

**scenario 2:**
image tag: 2

css: animation: imageAnimation 12s linear infinite 0s;

*not working properly white background showing once looping completed*

Comment: stackblitz is not working. please correct

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-with-multiple-images